# How to control the smart light (color , color tempreature, brightness)

Tags: actions-on-google

If the light is set to Red, and I want to modify the brightness.
But the Color Model(rgb or hsb) isn't support the brightness.same with color tempreature.
What should I do? Need to change to White light Model, then adjust the brightness?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the code you already have and the data you give it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to change the color and brightness both. If that is what you want to do then you have to implement two separate variables for brightness and color. The brightness cannot be controlled using just rgb or hsv, it uses separate variable and it ranges from 0-100.

Go through this:-
https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/colorsetting